# INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK - Error Message

Tags: android

I am trying out the basic "hello world" program on my LG Thrive phone that uses Android 2.2.1.  I have used an API level of 8 for the application, but still get the above error. Any other possible reason that this error is flagged ?

EDIT: I overcame this problem when I ran the application in my virtual emulator and then in the phone. The reason I did this was - I had to earlier change my API level from 15 to 8, and by merely modifying and saving the manifest file and the project properties - the apk file did not get updated. However it got updated once I ran the program on the virtual emulator. Any reason why the apk file did not get updated earlier ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are installing the apk on a phone using the shell, and you have already checked wheter you compiled it to a correct target (Api 8 o lesser), create another emulator to the Api 8 and try to compile it. If it fails, you are not configuring it correctly.

Comment: This error may happen when android:minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml is greater than your device OS version.