# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: android

I'm trying to deploy my Android app to a device running 2.3.7. I've set the API level to be 9 for both min and target.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```

When trying to deploy it gives the following error.

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try setting the target version to 10, since you are using a more updated version of Gingerbread. Also, is there anything more in the Logcat/Console, message-wise? Also, check to make sure you have all the SDKs installed with Eclipse.

Comment: Have you installed this version of SDK? If you are using eclipse just use the Manager and check the versions that you want to use and donwload it. You can get more info here: developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/

Comment: possible duplicate of [why is Android API level 9 obsolete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353503/why-is-android-api-level-9-obsolete)

Comment: There's no errors or relating info in the viewer, and I've installed every version of the SDK using the SDK Manager. Tried 3,5,8 and 10 yielding same results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618960/install-failed-older-sdk-error-message

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342280/install-failed-older-sdk-when-installing-apk

Answer (score 0):

API 9 seems to have been "deprecated" since all 2.3 to 2.3.2 `GINGERBREAD` devices should be at API 10 2.3.3 to 2.3.4 `GINGERBREAD_MR1`.

You should set your min to either API 8 or 10, which ever is more appropriate since 2.3.7 doesn't seem to exist.

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353503/why-is-android-api-level-9-obsolete) and the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I set the min to 8 and 10 and still get the same results. In fact I set them to 3 and 5 too still brings the same error. Could it be anything to do with the AnalyticsV2 lib being used with my app?

Comment: Might be. I tried figuring out if AnalyticsV2 needed a specific API and it doesn't seem to but I'm not sure.